# SQL Server : multi-join with tuple IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join 4 tables that have a somewhat complex relationship. Because of where this will be used, it needs to be contained in a single query, but I'm having trouble since the primary query and the IN clause query both join 2 tables together and the lookup is on two columns.

The goal is to input a `SalesNum` and `SalesType` and have it return the `Price`

Tables and relationships:

**sdShipping**

```
SalesNum[1]
SalesType[2]
Weight[3]
```

**sdSales**

```
SalesNum[1]
SalesType[2]
Zip[4]
```

**spZones**

```
Zip[4]
Zone[5]
```

**spPrices**

```
Zone[5]
Price
Weight[3]
```

Here's my latest attempt in T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    spp.Price 
FROM 
    spZones AS spz 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    spPrices AS spp ON spz.Zone = spp.Zone 
WHERE 
    (spp.Weight, spz.Zip) IN (SELECT ship.Weight, sales.Zip 
                              FROM sdShipping AS ship 
                              LEFT OUTER JOIN sdSales AS sales ON sales.SalesNum = ship.SalesNum 
                                                               AND sales.SalesType = ship.SalesType
                              WHERE sales.SalesNum = (?) 
                                AND ship.SalesType = (?));
```

SQL Server Management Studio says I have an error in my syntax near ',' (appropriately useless error message). Does anybody have any idea whether this is even allowed in Microsoft's version of SQL? Is there perhaps another way to accomplish it? I've seen the multi-key IN questions answered on here, but never in the case where both sides require a JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many databases do support `IN` on tuples.  SQL Server is not one of them.

Use `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT spp.Price 
FROM spZones spz LEFT OUTER JOIN
     spPrices spp
     ON spz.Zone = spp.Zone 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM sdShipping ship LEFT JOIN
                   sdSales sales 
                   ON sales.SalesNum = ship.SalesNum AND
                      sales.SalesType = ship.SalesType
              WHERE spp.Weight = ship.Weight AND spz.Zip = sales.Zip AND
                    sales.SalesNum = (?) AND
                    ship.SalesType = (?)
             );
```

Comment: You're a genius Gordon - that's really helpful, thanks! I'm still not getting any results but at least it's not giving me an error anymore... No more wasting time with that IN clause. I'll give credit as soon as I can figure out what piece is still missing to get the Price

Comment: @Typel . . . Your query is rather complicated.  One possibility is that the weights don't match -- that seems like a number that would be more of a range.

Comment: Good call, I had been using CEILING for weight in there at one point but must have tried dropping it after several mis-attempts. Also trying RTRIM on SalesNum and SalesType since those occasionally have blank characters at the end. Nothing yet but I feel like it's close...

Comment: Well at any rate, you've answered the original question - the rest is likely data tinkering on my part. Will close this up - thanks again for your help!